# Debugging powershell running in a remote process

Tags: debugging, powershell

I have a complex system I am inheriting that uses many many powershell (.ps1) scripts as part of its complex logic. The code is strewn about in a flat manner in a directory. So instead of trying to piece them together and learn the system by statically reading the code, I am hoping to let it run (I have a test environment) and learn what's happening under the hood by debugging the code. So this means I have to "attach" to the powershell host process and place breakpoints/step thru code.

Are there any tools available that make it easy to do this? I have looked at Powershell ISE, but there is no attach option. Tried VisualStudio 2013 and no dice there either (attached to Powershell_ise.exe with Script option, that didnt work either).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set-PSDebug` in your ps1 files or in base session ([documentation](http://ss64.com/ps/set-psdebug.html)). But this will be irritating process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell_ISE if you run the startup/main script in the ISE's console pane (the tool window with a prompt). Then any breakpoints you set in the opened script files will work.  Plus you can step through the code using ISE when you've started the script in this manner.